# ASP.Net MVC : Suppress redirect to default page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

There is a way to suppress redirect to default page in case that the web api return a 200 response and the message received is

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body><h2>Object moved to <a href="/default.aspx">here</a>.</h2></body></html>{"success":true,"message":""}
```

We've implemented a mechanism that popup the login form instead of redirecting to the Login page if the session expired. The session is correctly refreshed
but the call returns "Object moved to here ..." and the page is refreshed.

The login authentication is the standard Web forms  one.

**Web Api**:

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public dynamic RefreshSession(LoginModel model)
   {
    Refresh session implementation
    .........
   }
returns 200 and "Object moved to here ..."
```

**Angular call**

```
 return $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: service.Urls.RefreshSession,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json" },
                    transformResponse: angular.identity,
                    data: data
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
```

We used: `context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true`
but didn't work.

Comment: Look into formatting your question using the provided tools as your question is currently very difficult to read.

Comment: You question makes no sense. A 200 status code is not a redirect and will not cause a redirect.

Comment: yes, the Status Code 200 doesn't makes sense to redirect the page. But the response could be one of the reason.  <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body><h2>Object moved to <a href="/default.aspx">here</a>.</h2></body></html>{"success":true,"message":""}